# jQuery UI Dialog (as a bookmarklet) unable to open in webpages with frameset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, bookmarklet

I'm working on a bookmarklet which uses jQuery UI Dialog. I understand that frameset doesn't allow div to be inserted, thus the dialog won't show. Need some ideas to overcome this issue.

Comment: You mean if the bookmarklet is running in the scope of the frameset and the page in the frame is from another domain and you want to access it? Forget it. You will have to run it in the scope of the page

Comment: I understand same-origin policy, the web pages that are causing my dialog box not to show are those with frameset such as javadoc sites (webpages in frames are from the same origin).

Comment: I understand same-origin policy, the webpages that are causing my dialog box not to show are those with frameset such as javadoc sites (webpages in frames are from the same origin). The issue (if I'm not wrong) is frameset doesn't allow html elements underneath it, my <div> element cannot be inserted into the frameset and thus no dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You won't. You are being blocked by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: The webpages that give my bookmarklet problems are the javadoc sites where the webpages in frames are from the same origin so it's not that I violate the policy.